# Tkinter working in the terminal but not in sublime (mac)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, sublimetext3

I installed the latest version of Python on a clean mac. When I try to use tkinter in the terminal everything works (or at least tkinter._test() works well). But when I use sublime I get an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Python 3.7/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named tkinter
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Applications/Python 3.7/app.py"]
[dir: /Applications/Python 3.7]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I am aware that it is some kind of problem with the directory but I cannot figure out what the exact problem is or how to solve it. I installed Python in the default folder given by the installer, which created a folder in the applications folder.

Comment: Probably you should extend your path (where Python looks for the modules) with the location of `tkinter` module.

Comment: Afraid I have no idea how to do that... Could you explain or link a tutorial, please?